# Stack Navigator : Navigating from React Native Screen to Native Screen and then jumping back to React Native Screen?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Requirement is such that User goes to Login Screen (Built on React Native) -> PIN Screen (Native Screen) -> Device Registration Screen (Built on React Native)

I was able to go from Login Screen -> PIN Screen, but not able to go from PIN Screen to Device Registration Screen.

It goes without a doubt that the state should be preserved. i.e. if we click back from Device Registration Screen we should land on PIN Screen and again back is clicked from PIN Screen, we should land on Login Screen.

Navigation Implementation

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Login',
        header: null
      }
    },
    DeviceRegistration: {
      screen : DeviceRegistration,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Device Registration',
        header: null
      }
    },
   {
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
   }
);

const Navigation = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

LoginScreen Implementation

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, NativeModules, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-navigation';

class LoginScreen extends Component {

    _goToNativePinPage(){
        NativeModules.ChangeViewBridge.changeToNativeView();
    }

    render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        var s = require('../../styles/style');
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                <View style={s.container}>
                    <Text>This is Login page</Text>
                    <Button onPress={() => this._goToNativePinPage()} title="PIN PAGE"></Button>
                </View >
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('LoginScreen',() => LoginScreen);

export default Login;
```

Bridge implementation from React Native to Native

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface ChangeViewBridge : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
- (void) changeToNativeView;
@end
```

```
#import "ChangeViewBridge.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@implementation ChangeViewBridge

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(ChangeViewBridge);

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(changeToNativeView) {

  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  [appDelegate goToNativeView];
}

@end
```

Inside App Delegate

```
- (void) goToNativeView {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      UIViewController *vc = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil].instantiateInitialViewController;
      self.window.rootViewController = vc;
  });
}
```

Comment: Try renaming this? this._goToNativePinPage() tothis._goToNativePinPage and give it try?

Comment: @Karan Tewari that’s not the issue. Going to native page is working perfectly fine. While coming back from native to react native is the problem. I don’t know how it is done.